# Does SO use ASP.Net Identity or did they roll their own?

Tags: discussion, meta

I notice that SO is using DotNetOpenId and I have seen the data dump schema.

Is ASP.Net Identity used at all?
If yes, are roles and scopes used?

Comment: I'd doubt it.  SO is much older than Identity.